# .serialize() doesn't work for particular fom in Opera

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, opera

I'm stuck on strange behavior: for one of the forms `$().serialize()` method doesn't work  (returns empty string). Only in Opera (on Linux, 12.16). Works fine in Chromium, FF and Opera on Android.

Form is

```
<form id="new-story-form" role="form" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txt-storyname" class="control-label">Story name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="txt-storyname" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="num-storylength" class="control-label">Story length</label>
        <input type="number" name="length" class="form-control" id="num-storylength" value="20" min="10" max="500" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Начать</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript for submitting is:

```
        $("#new-story-form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var post_data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(post_data);

            $.post("/post", post_data ,function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                show_message("S", 'success');
                var update = setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);

            }).fail(function (err) {
                        $.each(err.responseJSON, function (index, value) {
                            console.log(index, value);
                            show_message(index + ' - ' + value, 'danger');
                        });

                    });
        });
```

if I look to `var post_data = $(this).serialize();` in the Opera debugger, `$(this)` contains normal form object, but `post_data` is `""`.

Is it something that I can miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the name "`length`" of the input, choose another name.

I guess it's a conflict with the [built-in property "length"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a form.

**There is a note in the jQuery-documentation:** *Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.*

Comment: yeah, thanks! Thought of possible `name="name"` problem but missed `name="length"`